# SQL Server full text search few words at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I understand that in order to find records that contain more than one word, I need to use AND between them, like this:

```
select * 
from table1 
where contains(name , '"bob" AND "marly"')
```

The problem is that my user doesn't type "bob" AND "marly", he types bob marly.
Before I start parsing this string and splitting it, is there a cleaner way to do this?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: you can use wild card '%'

Comment: It seems the full quotes are not helping you. Is select * from table1 where contains(name , 'bob AND marly') yielding better results?

Comment: The results are ok both ways.

Answer (score 0):

The below query will check if the string contains bob marly.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%'+'bob'+'%'+'marly'+'%'
```

Comment: Like is too slow. It's a huge table.